# Changing execution stack in x86 from Rust

Tags: assembly, rust, x86, inline-assembly

I am trying to manually set RSP and start execution at a custom address in Rust with inline x86_64 assembly.

I have this C code which works:

```
#include <stddef.h>

void __attribute ((noreturn)) jump_with_stack(size_t jump_addr, size_t *jump_stack) {
            __asm__ volatile ( \
                        "movq %[stack], %%rsp\n" \
                        "xor %%rdx, %%rdx\n" \
                        "jmp *%[entry]" \
                        : /* None  */ \
                        : [stack] "r" (jump_stack), [entry] "r" (jump_addr) \
                        : "rdx", "memory" \
                        );
}
```

This is the disassembly:

```
jump_with_stack:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        movq rax, %rsp
        xor %rdx, %rdx
        jmp *rcx
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

And this Rust code that does not:

```
#![feature(asm)]

pub unsafe extern fn rust_jump_with_stack(target: usize, targ_stack: *mut usize) -> ! {

    asm!("mov rsp, $0
         xor rdx, rdx
         jmp [$1]"
         :
         :"r"(targ_stack), "r"(target)
         : "rdx", "memory"
         : "intel");
    unreachable!();
}
```

Here is the rust disassembly:

```
example::rust_jump_with_stack:
    push    rax

    mov     rsp, rsi
    xor     rdx, rdx
    jmp     qword ptr [rdi]

    lea     rdi, [rip + .L__unnamed_3]
    lea     rdx, [rip + .L__unnamed_4]
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + std::panicking::begin_panic@GOTPCREL]
    mov     esi, 40
    call    rax
    ud2
```

(Both disassembly outputs are from Godbolt explorer)

I don't understand the difference between the two or what the difference in the generated code means.

Comment: Since you specified intel syntax, you got the first `mov` reversed.

Comment: Looks like you compiled your Rust code with optimization enabled, but C with `gcc -O0`.  That might be the default for both compilers; `-O0` is the default for GCC.

Comment: You might want to use `__attribute__((noinline))`  or maybe `__builtin_unreachable()` after the asm statement, to make sure the C function can't inline into a caller in an unsafe way.  I'm not sure if putting `noreturn` on the wrapper function is sufficient.

Comment: @Jester good catch. I've updated the question, but I still am receiving different behavior between the C code and rust code.

Comment: Obviously the C version puts `rbp` on the stack and sets it up as frame pointer while the rust version just pushes `rax` (presumably for aligmnent). Shouldn't really affect your outcome though. What is the "different behavior" anyway?

Comment: The C code correctly begins executing at the new "entry point" with the new stack frame, whereas the rust produces a SIGSEGV

Comment: You're still using AT&T syntax in your asm template, though!  `jmp *%rcx` is the AT&T version of `jmp rcx`.  And you're using `%` decorations on RDX.  In Intel syntax you should use `xor edx,edx` to zero RDX.  Also, if you have a pointer to a pointer, you want `jmp *(%[entry])` to match your Rust, or tell the compiler to deref it for you.  e.g. `"rm"(*jump_addr)` for a `void **jump_addr`.  Anyway, try Binary mode on Godbolt to actually assemble to machine code then disassemble, instead of just doing inline asm text substitution without showing that it will even assemble.

Comment: You'd have to check where the fault occurs. Also you should obviously verify that the argument for the stack is a writable memory of sufficient size and aligned properly and the jump target is executable. The fault may be in the called function too.

Comment: @PeterCordes - The AT&T syntax in the working C code doesn't seem to be a problem. I'm wondering why the rust code isn't working and what the difference in the disassembly could mean.

Comment: There is basically no difference in the assembly now except for stuff your target code should not depend on (`rax` vs `rbp` on the stack, `rbp` as frame pointer). Well actually ... do you want your target as a pointer? You might not want to use `[]` so try `jmp $1`.

Comment: Oh, then change the Rust version to match the C version, *removing* the extra level of indirection by using `jmp $1` to match AT&T `jmp *%1`.  In the AT&T, the `[entry]` is part of the syntax for the operand name, not part of an addressing mode.

Comment: That worked @PeterCordes, thank you. Feel free to post an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jmp [$1]` is an extra level of indirection that you don't have in your AT&T version.

AT&T `jmp *%1` is equivalent to Intel `jmp %1`.

Note that `%[entry]` is just a symbolic way of writing `%1`; the square brackets are part of the operand-name syntax and don't end up in the final asm output as an addressing-mode syntax.

(Also your question is a total mess because you use `-masm=intel` on Godbolt while your GNU C inline asm is written to be built with the default `-masm=att`.)

---

The other major differences are that GCC defaults to `-O0` (anti-optimized debug mode), while you built your Rust code with optimization enabled.

---

You should probably use `__builtin_unreachable()` after your C `asm("")` statement to make sure the compiler knows that execution really doesn't come out the other side of the asm statement.  I'd worry that marking the wrapper function `noreturn` might not be sufficient to prevent having the compiler assume it can defer a store until after the asm statement, after inlining.  (Jumping out of an `asm` statement normally requires `asm goto` for known labels, otherwise `__builtin_unreachable()` is recommended.)